# Find a function for z in the neighbourhood of a point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given $3x(2+3z)+y+e^z=1$ how do I show that it defines a $z$ as a function of $f(x,y)$ in the neighbourhood of $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the implicit function theorem, which you can get more details here: [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem). For your problem, it is now a matter of reworking it so that you can apply this result. Let $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(x, y, z) = 3x(2 + 3z) + y + e^z - 1$ and observe that $g(0, 0 ,0) = 0$. Furthermore, note that the partial derivative $\left.\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z}\right\vert_{(0, 0, 0)} = 1 \neq 0$. So then by the implicit function theorem, there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $(0, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a (unique) continuously differentiable function $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(0, 0) = 0$ and $g(x, y, f(x, y)) = 0$ for all $(x, y) \in U$. In other words, on $U$, $z$ is equal to a continuously differentiable function $f(x, y)$ so that $3x(2 + 3z) + y + e^z = 1$ holds.

Comment: Do I need to substitute the point (0,0,0) into the partial derivatives that is calculated?

Comment: Yes, the notation I used means "evaluated at".